# Is it possible to multiply a single number with multiple numbers and get the same value?

Tags: linear-algebra

What I am asking is kind of like an LCM of 2 numbers but they both must be multiplying with the same number to get the common multiple. It doesn't necessarily have to be the lowest, just any multiple. For instance lets take 2 variables `x` and `y`.Imagine,

> `xz = yz` where, `x and y` are integers, `x ≠ y`, `z` can be any Real number, `z ≠ 0`

Known values -> `x` and `y`

Unknown value -> `z`

Is such a mathematical equation possible? Like maybe at least using imaginary numbers? Is there a way to find `z`?

Just to be more clear, for eg; I have 2 numbers `7` and `9` and there exists some Real Number `r` such that `7r = 9r`, and `r ≠ 0`.
`r` can be any Real number such as fraction, irrational, positive, negative or even imaginary, doesn't matter.

Comment: If $z \ne 0$ and $xz=yz$, then it follows that $x=y$.

Comment: @MattiP. Yes, something like that except in both products after 32 there should be a common number (any real number, whether fraction or negative or positive but the absolute value should not be zero)

Comment: @Fred but the conditions are `x ≠ y` and `z ≠ 0`

Comment: Yes , I know. If $xz=yz$, then we have $z=0$ or $x=y$. In other words: if$x \ne y$ and $z \ne 0$, then $xz=yz$ is impossible.

Comment: You can also subtract $7r$ from $7r=9r$ to get $0=2r$ and dividing by $2$ gives $0=r$. This is ruled out, hence there is no solution left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
xz = yz \iff xz - yz = 0 \iff (x - y)z = 0.
$$
If $x,y,z$ are elements of a field (e.g. $x,y,z$ are all real numbers, or $x,y,z$ are all complex numbers), then this equation can only hold if $x-y = 0$ (which is to say that $x = y$) or if $z = 0$. So, the kind of equation you want is impossible in this context.

However, if we allow $x,y,z$ to be elements of [a ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) $R$ that contains [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor), then it is possible to have a solution to this equation for which $x \neq y$ and $z \neq 0$. For example, if we take $R = \Bbb Z/(6\Bbb Z)$ (the integers [modulo $6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)), then we find that the equation $xz = yz$ holds with $x = 1, y = 4, z = 2$. That is,
$$
1 \cdot 2 \equiv 4 \cdot 2 \pmod 6.
$$

Comment: Seems like you've got a right answer, but I am not so advanced in math to know what a ring and zero divisors are. I am gonna look them up and later come back and see if this solves it. If possible it'll be helpful if you elaborate the answer a bit.

Comment: @an4s911 I would suggest that you start by understanding the example of the integers modulo $6$. To summarize the rest: in general, a ring is a set of objects that act like numbers and have rules for addition and multiplication. One example is the integers modulo some integer $n$, another example is the set of polynomials (with coefficients from a field or from another ring), another example is the set of square matrices of a certain size. We say that a ring has "zero divisors" if it has solutions to the equation $pq = 0$ where both $p$ and $q$ are non-zero.